# Reads from Slave in Master/Slave Replication

Tags: mongodb

Does slave participate in read if read preference is set to secondaryPreferred() in master/slave setup of MongoDB?

I am using Mongodb java driver 2.9.3 with SlaveOkay option but do not see read distributed to slave?

Answer (score 0):

[SecondaryPreferred](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.9.3/) means that read from Slave if available, from Master otherwise. For your question, yes it should participate in read if it is available.

Comment: same is mine understanding too. While doing benchmarking with three server one master two slave total read query resolution is about 14000 Request Per second Which is also the case if i just hit one server instead master/slave replica set.